# Dynamically select columns with string variable in adf copy activity

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I want to copy tables from a SQL Server to a data lake and dynamically add certain columns based on the data type of existing columns. The tables in question vary in row and column size, but the main goal is to transform any column of type geometry into two new columns, one with the WKT string of the geometry and one with SRID information about the geometry. Here is an example of such a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stations](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StationNumber] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [StationName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Location] [geometry] NOT NULL,
    [LocationTypeTypeListItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [mLastModified] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [LocationRef] [geometry] NULL)
```

I managed to write this snippet of T-SQL

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(select_string, ', ') AS sstring
FROM (
        SELECT Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) as [SCHEMA_NAME]
    , object_NAME(c.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME
    , c.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
    , t.NAME AS DATA_TYPE
    , CONCAT(c.NAME, ' AS ', c.NAME) AS select_string
        FROM sys.all_columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        where Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) <> 'sys'
            and object_NAME(c.object_id) = 'Stations'
    UNION
        SELECT Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) as [SCHEMA_NAME]
    , object_NAME(c.object_id) AS TABLE_NAME
    , t.NAME AS DATA_TYPE
    , CONCAT(c.NAME, '.STSrid AS ', c.NAME, 'Srid') AS select_string
        FROM sys.all_columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        where Object_Schema_name(c.object_id) <> 'sys'
            and t.name = 'geometry'
            and object_NAME(c.object_id) = 'Stations'
 ) AS temp
```

This generates a list with the desired columns as a long string with the format

```
"Id AS Id, StationNumber AS StationNumber, StationName AS StationName, 
 Location.STAsText() AS Location, Location.STSrid AS 
 LocationSRID, [...]"
```

Now, when I try to use the string in a copy data activity, I get the following error

```
The identifier that starts with '["Active AS Active",
" DistanceToOutletKm AS DistanceToOutletKm"," Id AS Id",
" Location AS Location"," Location.STSrid AS Locatio' is
too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

One of the queries I tried in the Copy Data Activity looks like this:

```sql
'SELECT ' + [@{split(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].sstring, ',')}] +
' FROM ' + [@{item().table_schema}].[@{item().table_name}]
```

where the lookup activity executes the previous query to generate the list.

How can I get the copy data activity to understand that it needs to treat the string as a list of columns?

Comment: Can you please share an example of your data ?

Comment: @SallyDabbah I added some more text, code snippets and an example table schema. I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat) function to add string values and variables in the expression.

```
@concat('select ', activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].sstring, ' from ',item().schema_name,'.',item().table_name)
```

The input expression value of the copy data source:

[image]